# assign 2 fixed IPs from a subnet to a server via Heat

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, openstack-heat

Is there a way to assign multiple IPs from a subnet to a server using heat templates? I defined a resource for a port using fixed IPs, like below. I then used this resource to create a port on a OS::Nova::Server. But I see only one IP from the subnet assigned. Is there a way to assign to IPs from the subnet?

`resources:
  a_port:
    type: OS::Neutron::Port
    properties:
      network: "a_network"
      fixed_ips: [
       {
           "subnet_id" : "a_subnet_id",
           "subnet_id" : "a_subnet_id"
        }
      ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running on our system, I was able to use something like this to get a couple of IP addresses:

`resources:
  a_port:
    type: OS::Neutron::Port
    properties:
      network_id: "a_network"
      fixed_ips: 
      - subnet_id: a_subnet_id
      - subnet_id: a_subnet_id`

I think the problem you've got is both your `subnet_id` definitions are within the same map? (NB, there seems to have been some property name changes to drop _id in later releases.)

Comment: yes,, you are right. both subnet_id were the same map. I had a feeling this would not work, but I was trying it out. Our software requires 2 ips on that interface and the network i had access to did not have two subnets defined on it. But anyways, i paln to do this another way now. Thanx for your reply.

Comment: cool, no probs.  could you accept the answer if it's good for you? cheers, Matt